# How to get simple information through a crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a simple crawler that scrapes through this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping page, then proceeds to extract the 19 links from the See About section. This I manage to do, however I am also trying to extract the first paragraph from each of those 19 links and this is where it stops "working". I get the same paragraph from the first page and not from each one. This is what I have so far. I know there might be better options for doing this but i want to stick to BeautifulSoup and simple python code.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'

data = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')


def visit():
    try:
        p = soup.p
        print(p.get_text())
    except AttributeError:
        print('<p> Tag was not found')


links_todo = []
links = soup.find('div', {'class': 'div-col'}).find_all('a')
for link in links:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        links_todo.append(urljoin(url, link.attrs['href']))

while links_todo:
    url_to_visit = links_todo.pop()
    print('Now visiting:', url_to_visit)
    visit()
```

Example of the first print

```
Now visiting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial
Web scraping, web harvesting, or web data extraction is data scraping used for extracting data from websites. The web scraping software may directly access the World Wide Web using the Hypertext Transfer Protocol or a web browser. While web scraping can be done manually by a software user, the term typically refers to automated processes implemented using a bot or web crawler. It is a form of copying in which specific data is gathered and copied from the web, typically into a central local database or spreadsheet, for later retrieval or analysis.
```

Intended function should be that it prints the first paragraph for every new link printed, not the same paragraph from the first link. What do I need to do in order to fix this? Or any tips on what I am missing. I am fairly new to python so I am still learning the concepts as I work on things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your code you define `data` and `soup`. Both are tied to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping`.

Every time you call `visit()`, you print from `soup`, and `soup` never changes.

You need to pass the url to `visit()`, e.g. `visit(url_to_visit)`. The `visit` function should accept the url as an argument, then visit the page using `requests`, and create a new soup from the returned data, then print the first paragraph.

Edited to add code explaining my original answer:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
start_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'
# Renamed this to start_url to make it clear that this is the source page 
data = requests.get(start_url).text
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
 
 
def visit(new_url): # function now accepts a url as an argument
    try:
        new_data = requests.get(new_url).text # retrieve the text from the url
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_data, 'html.parser') # process the retrieved html in beautiful soup
        p = new_soup.p
        print(p.get_text())
    except AttributeError:
        print('<p> Tag was not found')
 
 
links_todo = []
links = soup.find('div', {'class': 'div-col'}).find_all('a')
for link in links:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        links_todo.append(urljoin(start_url, link.attrs['href']))
 
while links_todo:
    url_to_visit = links_todo.pop()
    print('Now visiting:', url_to_visit)
    visit(url_to_visit) # here's where we pass each line to the visit() function
```

Comment: I understand the gist of what you are trying to explain but could you show me through an example? The way I look at is the whole code must be restructured then? Because one section works fine, finding the links and putting them in a list. Only thing that doesn't seem to work is the actual visit function that doesn't take in the new URL's as parameters as you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, see my code in the edited answer. Function accepts url, retrieved the content, creates new_soup, and gets first paragraph from that. When calling the function we pass the url we want it to visit. Make sense?

Comment: Okay I understand what you mean now. What I cant wrap my head around is how it manages to find the new URL's then I am not defining them until I use the soup again to narrow my search in the for links loop! I understand what it does and how it does it, its just the order of things that messes with me...

Comment: The function definition is loaded but the function is not run until you call it. So when the program executes it does the following: 1) evaluate start_url, retrieve data, create soup (for the start_url page only). 2) Create a function object for `visit` so this is ready to be called when needed ... nothing is done with `visit` at this stage. 3) process the soup object from start_url to find the links on the start page and place them in a list. 4) Run the `while` loop, which passes each link from your list to the visit function, downloads that page and extracts the first paragraph.

Comment: I think I understand better now, thanks for the reply and the help!